# How to replace Android with Ubuntu (or anything less) on my Remix Mini

Tags: server, kernel, permissions, android, minecraft

I have a Remix Mini with 2 GB RAM, 16GB internal storage (14.3GB actual size) and it's based on arm64 (aarch64) architecture. I'm going to replace this with Linux because I'm trying to convert this machine to a Minecraft server, so that I can let players join a 24 hours running server. So I have a question. Is there actually such a thing as a nice tutorial about replacing Android with Linux on a Remix Mini? So can I? Is it possible? I know it's possible. Do not say impossible in an answer, unless you are 100% sure about your solution. I know. When I tried everything like Linux Deploy, userLAnd, Anlinux (Termux) I found that the only thing now i can do is replacing Android with Linux on the Remix Mini.

My experience with Linux Deploy:

It's the most trash garbage app ever made for Android. Why did I say this? Because it's a piece of trash to begin with. First I rooted my device and thanks to the XDA developer who helped me to do it, and then I installed Busybox, then I checked that the kernel version is correct and meets requirements, it's (3.19.70) then I started the Linux. After installation I got error from running vnc: `chmod not found`. What the hell was that?

I just commented a question on their GitHub and they said: your kernel is old and it must be 3.2 or you can't do anything, so I just put Linux Deploy out of my mind into the trash so I know it's the minimum requirements (3.0), but they said at GitHub it's (3.2). Let's actually throw this piece of garbage out of our minds.

My experience with Termux (no Anlinux):

I successfully installed Java from source package, then I started the server and all my dreams have been ruined by a `/tmp` permissions error. after that I used the chmod to give read and write permissions to `/tmp` directory then I got the same error, even when my `/tmp` is open.

My experience of working with userLAnd (Linux VM)

It's goddamn slow and it used 71% of memory. Who is stupid enough to run a 120 player Minecraft server with almost 200MB of memory! OK yeah, I'm  pretty sure, I'm not.

My experience of working with Anlinux (Termux).

The same thing as -->userLAnd, over 80% memory usage and yeah everyone, no way. I give up.

Then I made this huge forum maybe I found someone to help me make my dreams true, so can I install a Linux distro on a Remix Mini Android base device? Can someone help me? I mean like (Ubuntu Touch, etc.).

Comment: You might get better help on the more generic https://unix.stackexchange.com/ site

Comment: Can you boot from a USB or external HDD?

Comment: It's theoretically possible to get decent Minecraft server performance on an ARM device: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Minecraft+server

Comment: hey @User24601ill try it

Comment: @karel wat r u talking about? its raspberry pi, not remix mini 16gb, 4gb ram.

Comment: You bought a lemon.

Comment: @SimpliFixed no its an android-base device, not an opensource linux device.